# Flash Builder 4.5 Profiler not finding memory leak

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I'm working with a large modular app, and most of the swfs were made in Flash Professional. When I load the app in the Flash Builder Profiler, the memory usage appropriately goes up and down as I add and remove modules. When I flip between two modules many times, I end up with the current memory in the Profiler more or less where I started at around 2 megs. System.totalMemory, however, shows that the flash player has only been allocating memory and is currently using 106 megs. Is there a certain bug known to do this, or is there a better way to detect memory leaks? I'm using the latest flash player debug version.

Note: The SWF modules are all permitting debugging, and the Profiler picks up objects in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger)'s object allocation graph to see if it gives you different information.  If the memory is rising regardless of the object count, it might be a leak in Flash Player itself.

*Disclaimer: I wrote this debugger.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you disable any Exclusion filters, several of which are present by default. Once you remove those filters, the memory column in the profiler will add up to 106 megs instead of 2 megs.